# How to fix assertion error using playwright?

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

I'm using playwright to do e2e testing to check if the email is exists or not, and while I run my tests its said :
"Finished test flow with status passed"

But its show me that the test is failed because i have **assertion error** and not because i do something wrong

this is a piece my code:

```
const fillEmail = async (page: Page, value: string) =>
    await page.fill("email-for-test", value);

const fillPassword = async (page: Page, value: string) =>
    await page.fill("password-for-test", value);


  await fillName(page, name);
  await fillEmail(page, email);
  const res = await page.locator('.email-error').innerText(); // return error string
  expect(res).toContain("Email is already in used");
```

[image]
and i got error, you can see in the picture that I uploaded
any idea how to remove or fix this error

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You code actually works. You can also use `page.textContent()`

```js
const res = await page.locator('.email-error').innerText(); 
expect(res).toContain("Email is already in use");

const text = await page.textContent('.email-error');
expect(text).toContain("Email is already in use");
```

Comment: I know that my code work, but somehow i still get this - assert error its like try to do something on thing that dont exists

Answer (score 1):

How about you just use this:

```js
await expect(page.locator('.email-error')).toContainText(
  'Email is already in used',
  {timeout: 7000}
)
```

Also Check if the last word of the assertion message is `used` or `use`.

You can also use the text selector and assert it to be visible. Something like this:

```js
await expect(page.locator('text=Email is already in use')).toBeVisible({
  timeout: 7000,
})
```

Comment: Can you check the locator and also check that the error message is actually appearing?

Comment: I did what u said i got the same error ,but your way is more clean :)
its suppose to be "Email is already in use"  my mistake

Comment: I check it menualy and also add sleep after i click on submit the error is appear and also the locator, i did managed to get it with css selector.

Comment: You don't need to add sleep, expect assertions will retry by default till 5 seconds. If you want to increase the timeout, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still get this error :(  , maybe something in my flow cause that i dont know. its look like the thing that i want to do assert dont exists but it dose :(

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the HTML of the element?

Comment: I add a image if the html , but i think that the problem is in the except how in playwirght i can compare between string and array of string?

Comment: You also directly use the text and assert it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

i soulve this one by upgrade playwright library,
From v1.15 to v1.25

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).